# Multiple DateTime property validator?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have an entity in C# with multiple DateTime properties, each one of this properties means an expirationDate for some license.

```
public class TestA
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public DateTime changedAt {get; set;}
  public DateTime LicenseN1 {get; set;}
  public DateTime LicenseN2 {get; set;}
  public DateTime LicenseN3 {get; set;}
  public DateTime LicenseN4 {get; set;}
}
```

*not all the DateTime properties needs to be check. (like the createdAt, UpdatedAt, etc...)

I have a service where i need to check if any of the Licenses are expired.

```
public bool IsExpired(DateTime? expirationDate)
{
  return expirationDate < DateTime.Now;
}
```

In case it is, so i need to add the expiration Date of this license and a especific message of this License to an object and return to my front-end>

```
public class ExpiredLicensesMessage
    {
        public DateTime PendencyDate { get; set; }
        public string PendencyMessage { get; set; }
    
    }
```

for that i created an Dictionary.

```
public class PendencyDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> ExpirationMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"LicenseN1 ", "LicenseN1 is expired"},
        {"LicenseN2 ", "This license require an update"},
        {"LicenseN3 ", "Some different message"},
        {"LicenseN4 ", "Some different message"},
        {"NameOfTheLicenseProperty", "Some message"},
    };
}
```

and then if the IsExpired method returns true, i get the message from my dictionary passing the name of the property that is expired

What i`m trying to do is.

avoid a lot of If`s in my code to check each License.

Is that a way so i can call the IsExpired method inside an foreach or something like that?
Or would it have an better approach for that?.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is "lot's of ifs" ? Show code that you are talking about, what exact problem you have with it and what kind of help you are looking for.

Comment: That would be easier if you had a collection of dates instead of specific properties. Is that an option?

Comment: One lesson I learned in my long career: don't sacrifice clarity for elegance. Just do four ifs. Everybody will understand the code and I guess it's not liable to change any time soon. Encapsulate the check in the class itself.